# How do I split a piece of Chinese text into individual characters?

Tags: scala, text, machine-learning, nlp

I'm working on a machine learning project, where I'm building a Naive Bayes classifier over Chinese text. I want to use n-grams of Chinese characters as features, so I need to be able to split the text into unigrams (individual characters), bigrams (sequences of two characters), and so forth. (I don't care about special tokenization and such -- I just want raw characters as n-grams.)

How do I do this in Scala? I tried `text.sliding(2)` to get bigrams, but this doesn't quite seem to work. (I'm guessing because Chinese characters are not a single byte like they are in English?)

Comment: Hm, can you, please, add some inside, why it doesn't work? I've tried sliding(2) on "囗土夊米" and got the following bigrams: `囗土`, `土夊`, `夊米` which is pretty much looks like a desired result

Comment: Hmm, when I try `sliding(2)` on that string, I get `List(?, ??, ??, ?, ??, ??, ?, ??, ??, ?, ??)` [which doesn't have the desired length].

Comment: Ah, the problem was that I wasn't using UTF-8 by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general this is a question about the proper handling of Unicode in Java and therefore Scala as well. From my cursory glance at the internet there doesn't seem to "one true way" to handle Unicode in Java. I'm not a NLP person, so my understanding of *what* you want to do may be incorrect.

```
val text = "囗土夊米"  

val unigrams = text.toCharArray 

/* With the constraint unigrams is even, without the toString you get weird coercions */
val bigrams = 
  for (i <- 0 until unigrams.length if i % 2 == 0) yield unigrams(i).toString + unigrams(i + 1)
```

Something like that should be easy to generalize to a set of n-gram functions that will extract what you need, these being simple naive implementations of course.

Comment: Hmm, so when I run that piece of code, my `unigrams` variable is an array of size 12. Do you get an array of size 4?

Comment: @grautur Ensure your environment is using UTF8, e.g. when running scala on the command line: ```scala  -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"``` the above code would give you an array of size 4 and 2 bigrams.

Answer (score 0):

Try mecab.  I use mecab to create tokens for japanese and chinese.  Once mecab is installed...the the python api's.

See this reference.

[n-gram name analysis in non-english languages (CJK, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034881/n-gram-name-analysis-in-non-english-languages-cjk-etc)

See this on how to install mecab.

http://nlp.solutions.asia/?tag=ubuntu